# Sens du mot "ravin"

Tags: sens

Bonjour,

> *Connais le Masculin,
>
> Adhère au Féminin,
>
> Sois le Ravin du monde.
>
> Quiconque est le Ravin du monde,
>
> La vertu constante ne le quitte pas.
>
> Il retourne à l'état d'enfance.*
>
> Lao-tseu

Je n'ai pas bien compris le sens du mot "ravin" dans l'expression "ravin du monde" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« La vallée mystérieuse » , source de la vie et de l'énergie (féminine) primordiale (Cf les yoginī cachemiries), correspondent plus à Lao Tseu lié à la Nature et à la spiritualité, en opposition à Confucius, adepte des rituels
proches du bouddhisme et du Ravin masculin.

Réponse de @Personne.

Answer (score 1):

Il faudrait un specialiste de Lao Tseu, mais j'imagine que la traduction est plus poétique et mystique que géologiquement rigoureuse. Le sens entendu ici est plutôt celui d'un *cirque* ou d'une *vallée* fermée qui accueille un lac.

Etre le ravin du monde, c'est être le recipient de la vertu qui s'y accumule sans déborder.

Comment: Sur le web je vois des traductions anglaises “valley”, “stream”, “flowing stream”, “ravine”, “channel”, “brook”. Donc l'originale suggère probablement plutôt un cours d'eau (qui, accessoirement, coule dans une vallée) qu'un lac. Je suis incapable de juger l'original.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' — « La vallée mystérieuse » , source de la vie et de l'énergie (féminine) primordiale (Cf les yoginī cachemiries), correspondent plus à Lao Tseu lié à la Nature et à la spiritualité, en opposition à Confucius, adepte des rituels proches du bouddhisme et du Ravin masculin.

Comment: @Personne vous pouvez répondre à m'a question comme ça je pourrai l'accepter 

Comment: @NotCool … https://french.stackexchange.com/users/848/personne?tab=profile :-)